# How to configure gradle that after rebuild changes in the assets folder are also included

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-assets

How can I execute a gradle build such that changes in the assets folder are also included in this build? (Instant run is disabled.)

I dont want to use `:app:uninstallAll` before Gradle-aware Make because I also want to keep the settings of my App in the Emulator.